# WebView открываеться в браузере, а нужно в фрагменте

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, webview, replace

Есть проблема, пытаюсь сделать замену фрагмента на фрагмент.
Есть активити и 2 фрагмента, пытаюсь заменить фрагмент через активити на другой фрагмент. В последней передаеться ссылка на открытие в WebView. Тут все хорошо, кроме того, что ссылка открываеться в Браузере, а не в фрагменте.
Вот код Fragment2:

```
 public class Fragment2 extends WebViewFragment 
  {    
   private static final String TAG_HREF="href";
   final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, null);

    return v;
     }
  }
```

Думаю, проблема тут. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Alerx, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первая же [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170911/webview-inside-fragment-android-opening-outside-of-the-app-in-a-browser) на запрос гуглу

> webviewfragment android open in browser

Предлагает такое решение: (вставить код надо после строчки:

> View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, null);

```
String url = "http://somesite.ru";
WebView wv = new WebView(context); 
// или 
// WebView wv = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.my_webview_id);

wv.loadUrl(url);
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() 
{
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}
});
```

Comment: Как всегдп спасибо))) но есть небольшое НО. ссылка береться в фрагменте, через интерфейс передается в Активити, а вот активити должно передать ссылку в Фрагмент2. но почему то не отдает, или я не пойму как передатвать.
Если не сложно подскажите, даю ссылку на проект https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzAmtBtDzFbtSnlzUG5aTnVJU28/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Alerx, вы же не всерьёз предлагаете мне за вас писать ваш проект? Оформите проблему в виде вопроса - будет разбираться.

А способов передачи данных меж активити и фрагментом множество.

Comment: Нет конечно, я сам все сделаю. Я никак доклада не могу понять работу фрагментоы. Просто взглянуть на проблему целиком.

Comment: Даже если бы у меня не было своего кода, который надо править, я бы не смог запустить ваш код, т.к. у вас Android Studio + Gradle, а у меня Eclipse.

Comment: плохо! ну что ж поделаешь... буду дальше головой об стенку биться! =) 
спасибо огромное за потраченое время)

Comment: @Alerx, ответ-то мой вопрос решил?

Comment: Нет. Нифига. У меня уже крыша едет